# Adding Dollar Sign ($) Automatically In Edit Text for Android Studio

Tags: android

I would like to have an edit text that would automatically input a dollar sign before the number. Android Studio

Example
$500

**EDIT:**

The addition of the $ should take place when the edit text is used (when tapped). The Currency will be in CAD. However the dollar sign will act as a reminder for what the field is

Comment: What have you tried? When should this addition take place - before they start typing, or after?  Why include the $ in the text box rather than using some type of a label?  Are you using local currency from the device, or are you using USD (or CAD, etc.)?

Comment: The addition of the $ should take place when the edit text is used (when tapped). The Currency will be in CAD. However the dollar sign will act as a reminder for what the field is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add an onChange listener and insert the $ after the user is done input.

```
private EditText yourEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        yourEditText.setText("$" + yourEditText.getText().toString());
      }
      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}
```

Comment: You should override  `afterTextChanged` and all the others.

Comment: Add  `if (yourEditText.getText().toString().startsWith("$")) return;` to prevent the code from adding another $ sign everytime you change the text.

Comment: this can cause an infinite loop

Comment: @Thommy Using your suggestion didn't fix my problem, I kept on getting new dollar signs, from some reason all the new characters were added at the beginning of the string. I fixed it by doing: `yourEditText.setText("$" + yourEditText.getText().toString().replace("$", ""));` instead.

Answer (score 2):

My solution unsing kotlin and databinding (but actually the essence is in the text watcher):

XML Part:

```
 <EditText
        ...
        android:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.currencyTextWatcher}"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="$1234567890"
        />
```

TextWatcher implementation:

```
val currencyTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        when {
            editable.isNullOrEmpty() -> return
            Regex("\\$\\d+").matches(editable.toString()) -> return
            editable.toString() == "$" -> editable.clear()
            editable.startsWith("$").not() -> editable.insert(0, "$")
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) = Unit 
}
```

Comment: not working for pound symbol

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to allow currency amounts to be entered while keeping the currency format. For example:
On the empty input field you enter 1, then the output should be $0.01. If I add another digit (say 0), then the output string should be $0.10. Adding yet another digit (say 5) should yield $1.05. And so forth...

Here's some sample code to add currency formatting to the on text change listeners for an edittext field.

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

//This class is for entering currency amount while keeping the right format as the user enters values
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private final EditText et;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        this.et = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        //After all the text editing, if there is a string to validate - format it
        if (s != null && !s.toString().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                //Take the input string and remove all formatting characters
                String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "").replace("$","").replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()), "");
                //Pass the altered string to a number
                Number n = df.parse(v);
                //Get the decimal point correct again
                n = n.doubleValue() / 100.0;
                //Reformat the text with currency symbols, grouping places etc.
                et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
                //Add the Dollar symbol ($)
                et.setText("$".concat(et.getText().toString()));
                //Move the editing cursor back to the right place
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length());

            } catch (NumberFormatException | ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else //if the input field is empty
        {
            et.setText("$0.00");
        }

        et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```

Next you just link this new event listener class to your EditText input field

```
TextInputEditText mCashAmount = mView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput_CashAmount);
mCashAmount.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(mCashAmount));
```

Comment: setSelection was a missing piece that's very useful.

Comment: what is df in code?

Comment: Please edit your code: df should be replaced with dfnd

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your EditText and Hint Text inside a view and set custom background on them.

**dialog_input.xml**

```
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_text_border_round_corners"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_31sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_text_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="£"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/amount_txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**bg_text_border_round_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#33000000"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Output from my dialog**

[image: Output Example]

Answer (score 0):

> Just add the setOnFocusChangeListener on editext and based on focus
> show/hide the dollar sign.

check the below kotlin code.

```
edtTransferAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
           if(hasFocus){
               if(edtTransferAmount.text.isEmpty()){
                   edtTransferAmount.setText("$ ")
               }
           }else{
               if (edtTransferAmount.text.length <= 2){
                   edtTransferAmount.setText("")
               }
           }
        }
```

> if you want to prevent the dollar sign from clearing.

```
edtTransferAmount.addTextChangedListener {
            if(edtTransferAmount.isFocused){
            if(edtTransferAmount.text.length < 2){
                edtTransferAmount.setText("$ ")
                edtTransferAmount.setSelection(2)
            }}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack Compose solution:

```kotlin
BasicTextField(
    value = amount,
    onValueChange = { amount = it },
    visualTransformation = { text ->
        TransformedText(
            text = AnnotatedString(text.text + "$"),
            offsetMapping = OffsetMapping.Identity
        )
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
editText.setText("$");
```

When user tap on editText then editText prefilled with "$" sign , but the disadvantage of this is that user can able to delete the "$" sign.

Another solution to this problem is that,set editText left drawable to "$" or "$ image".When user triggers an action like save or submit then add "$" before the editText.

```
String temp = "$";
String finalString = temp + editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Are you really too lazy to press CTRL+K?

Comment: And this solution doesn't work, when you set the text of the `editText` to $, the whole text will be replaced by it.