# EditText locks up my app whenever OnTextChanged activates

Tags: android, android-edittext

So, I am trying to get an edit text to put a dollar sign ($) in front of the input text after a user enters it using the following code. Whenever I try to enter anything into the edittext it locks the whole app. I have tried removing the code and the box works fine. What should I change? Or should I use an entirely different solution?

Code:

```
final EditText minAmt = fragView.findViewById(R.id.minPayment);

    minAmt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            minAmt.setText("$" + minAmt.getText().toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
        { }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
        { }
    });
```

Do I need to finish the overrides for on- and before- text changed? 
For reference, I got this code frame from another thread here: [Adding Dollar Sign ($) Automatically In Edit Text for Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834649/adding-dollar-sign-automatically-in-edit-text-for-android-studio)

Comment: `It locks the whole app` means what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app freezes because you enter an infinite loop. Calling setText inside afterTextChanged will call afterTextChanged. The solution is :

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    minAmt.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    minAmt.setText("$" + minAmt.getText().toString());
    minAmt.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I missed that possibility in the documentation for the two.